# Rails not using correct version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-1.9

**New information**

This is what happens with `rails console`:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.1)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "1.8.7"
```

There's something really weird going on here - the prompt says `1.9.2` but `RUBY_VERSION` shows `1.8.7`.

---

I'm using RVM, but I'm having problems with Rails on Ubuntu.

```
$ which ruby
/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby

$rvm list
rvm rubies
=> ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i686 ]
```

But if I do `gem env` I get

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin
```

and when I run Rails, if I do `puts RUBY_VERSION` it outputs `1.8.7`.

In fact, in `irb`, `RUBY_VERSION` gives `1.9.2` but in `rails console` it gives `1.8.7`.

The main problem is that it's failing when it gets to my JSON-style hash-literals.

I've tried various approaches of uninstalling rvm, rails, bundler, etc. but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

### EDIT:

Here is the output of `rvm info`:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux ubie 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.8.6 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p290"
    date:         "2011-07-09"
    platform:     "i686-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2011-07-09 revision 32553"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
    ruby:         "/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/nick/.rvm/bin:/home/nick/local/node/bin:/home/nick/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290:/home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
    IRBRC:        "/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

but still `gem env` tells me that in the RubyGems Environment the Ruby version is `1.8.7`. I just don't get it.

Comment: looks like you edited your question - the PATH looks good. What happened to the /usr/local reference I saw earlier?

Comment: @Tilo I'm not sure what you're talking about with /usr/local... where did you see that?

Comment: hmmm.. sorry, I thought I saw that before in your question. my bad.

Comment: can you try to install RVM and Ruby 1.9.2 for a new user account, and see if that works?  I suspect there's something messed-up either with the ~/.rvm install you have, or some remainder of an earlier system-wide RVM install. Or omething during the compilation of Ruby 1.9.2 seemed to have gone wrong.

Comment: if you can get this to work for a new user account, then it's a good indication that your ~/.rvm is messed up, and I would `rm -rf ~/.rvm` and re-install RVM and Ruby from scratch on your original account.

Comment: I've already nuked RVM from my original account, still having the same problem. I think there's something weird going on with the system rubygems. I'll try a new account, but I'm preparing to just do a clean install of Ubuntu soon - I think I've managed to make it completely fubar with all my poking around.

Comment: Can you paste your `rake about`, please?

Comment: @Tilo Not yet, I haven't had the time :( Still looking at a clean install - I haven't customised the OS that much so I won't lose much. Cheers for your help :)

Answer (score 6):

You should set default ruby like:

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

This will override system installed ruby with rvm one.

Updated:

notme, thank you for remark

Leading double hyphen before default is significant to set default ruby.

Below listed detailed & self-explained example, enjoy:

```
$ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i686-linux]

$rvm list
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i386 ]

$rvm use 1.9.2 --default
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290

$rvm list default

Default Ruby (for new shells)

   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i386 ]

$rvm use default
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290

$ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]

$rvm list 

rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i386 ]
```

Comment: Already done this. `RUBY_VERSION` in `rails console` still showing `1.9.2`.

Comment: obviously you forgot to start new session, reopen your shell window

Comment: Nope, I've restarted my session, restarted my computer, still `1.8.7` in `rails console` and `1.9.2` in `irb`.

Comment: I know how to set the default Ruby with RVM, and I've done that. `irb` uses 1.9.2, `ruby -v` shows 1.9.2, `rvm-prompt` shows 1.9.2, but Rails is *still* using 1.8.7.

Comment: strange deal, i don't know out of the box way to force rails use different version of ruby, as all of them rely on ruby executable from the current shell. Also I hope you have not modified rails executables and using default one. I also suppose that you did not run any .rvmrc, between version tests! (:  Challenging line from gem env: `- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8`, points to system-not-rvm ruby and other paths are rvm based. If you are still in trouble, post `rvm  info` output

Comment: I've just posted the `rvm info` output as you suggested. It is strange that `gem env` is showing Ruby 1.8 - that's got to be something to do with it.

Comment: Thank you my good friend.. After one day, rails is on fire again!

Answer (score 4):

Most likely Culprit:

Check your PATH environment variable by typing `printenv PATH` in the shell -- /usr/bin might come before wherever RVM installs it's Rubies -- but you don't want that when using RVM!!

If /usr/bin comes before the RVM-location,  when checking for programs, it will take /usr/bin/ruby -- the Ruby which came with your LINUX (most likely 1.8.7) -- not the RVM default ruby (which is 1.9.2)

You can double check this like this by asking your system `which ruby`:

```
which ruby                           # this should be an RVM path! , not /usr/bin
ruby --version                       # you want this to be 1.9.2
/usr/bin/ruby --version              # the old system default Ruby is most likely 1.8.7

~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
~/.rvm/rubies/default/bin/ruby --version
```

**Check your PATH environment variable -- make sure that the directory where your RVM ruby version is installed comes FIRST, before /usr/bin**

e.g. in my PATH, the ~/.rvm/...  comes first, then /usr/local/bin, then /usr/bin (with a couple of other dirs of course)

---

as mentioned before, `rvm --default use 1.9.2` , so you get the default Ruby version in any new shell.

Looks like you have installed RVM system-wide under /usr/local.

IMHO system-wide installation can be a mess when upgrading gems, and it can cause a couple of problems going forward.

I would not recommend doing that!  I had a longer email discussion with Wayne Seguin, and even he uses local user RVM for his environments.

Check the RVM docu - it says there:  Please note that Single-User supercedes Multi-User [...RVM installation].

That means that if you have installed RVM system-wide, and you also (accidentially?) installed it for a user account, then for that user, the locally installed RVM takes precedence. This is an extra pit-fall which is easy to avoid by not installing system-wide in the first place :)

Personally, I would uninstall the system-wide RVM and install it only for the relevant user(s), who can then more easily install their gems themselves without interfering with other users.

Finally: when installing local to the user account, make sure that you install your gems specifically for the correct Ruby version, and that you do not use sudo to install the gems!

hopes this helps!
good luck!

---

**EDIT**

If you're getting different output from RUBY_VERSION than your irb or rails console prompt, then there must be something amiss with the way Ruby was compiled / installed.  **This looks more and more like you need to re-install RVM and your Ruby version 1.9.2**, but first check your PATH, to make sure that's not the culprit.

---

A Sanity Check, to check if there is interference from your LINUX installation:

create a new user account, do a new RVM install for that user and install Ruby 1.9.2 -- then try if it works in that account,  or if it shows the same problems.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `.rvmrc` file in your user directory?

```
$ cat ~/.rvmrc
=> export rvm_path="/home/nick/.rvm"
```

It should look something like that?

And also check you've set up a `.bashrc` file like this:

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: YES! Look for .rvmc files in your home and in the project's directory.  I had tried all of the above options, like the --default, etc, etc. and I believe (it was a little while ago) that deleting the .rvmc files was the final (and not too obvious!) trick. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Passenger or Pow to run your Rails apps? If so you'll need to set the server to use rvm 1.9.2

See section 2.3 here, for example: http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2

Or for passenger: http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/

Comment: Nope, WEBrick (and the same thing happens when running RSpec).

Answer (score 1):

I would go for bad gem/rails install:

```
gem empty
gem update --system
gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't use sudo with RVM. I ran into an issue like this where I had 2 different locations for Ruby and my gems.

Answer (score 0):

PATH is probably wrong - check `printenv PATH`

Comment: `printenv PATH` gives `/home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/nick/.rvm/bin:/home/nick/local/node/bin:/home/nick/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Answer (score 0):

Man, I was having this exact problem and the way I solved it was by reinstalling bundler. It seems that bundler was caching the RUBY_VERSION to 1.8.7.

I'm not using rvm, I had to use this to set the default ruby version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
sudo update-alternatives --config gem
```

And then, I reinstalled bundler and it worked!

Hopefully you can solve it with this approach