# Ruby on Rails - Error on installfest deploying rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I've been trying to go through the Installfest steps on the Rails Bridge Installfest http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/deploy_a_rails_app and can't get past this one error I'm getting.

I am at Step 2.5 on the Deploy A Rails App and am using a Mac with High Sierra. I haven't had a problem before running into step 2.5. When I do "git push heroku master", I get an error that states:

```
remote: Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby-2.3.7.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
remote: Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby-2.3.7.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
remote: 
remote: !
remote: ! An error occurred while installing ruby-2.3.7
remote: ! 
remote: ! This version of Ruby is not available on Heroku-18. The minimum supported version
remote: ! of Ruby on the Heroku-18 stack can found at:
remote: ! 
remote: ! [link]
remote: !
remote: ! Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote: ! Push failed
```

An error occurred while installing ruby-2.3.7

However, when I do Ruby -V, I get

```
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-darwin17], the version it says I need.
```

If anyone can help or provide advice, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You can find solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354444/how-can-i-solve-this-trouble-to-deploy-a-rails-app-to-heroku?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not on your computer but on Heroku. You use a version of Ruby that is not supported by Heroku anymore – see [Heroku's list of support Ruby version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions).

You can update the Ruby version that Heroku should use by adding the following line to your `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "2.3.8"                     # <- this is the line to add
```

See [selecting a version of Ruby](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions#selecting-a-version-of-ruby)

You might want to consider updating to the latest Ruby version (currently `2.5.3`). But that means that you might need to update Ruby on your computer too – how to do that depends on your OS and how you installed Ruby.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I appreciate your help. I updated Ruby in my test_app, but then when I wanted to make a new application, it reverted back to the old one?