# can't push app to heroku, even though specified ruby version matches mine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

> -----> Ruby app detected
>
> -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
>
> Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby-2.3.8.tgz
>   -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
>
> Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby-2.3.8.tgz
>   -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
>
> !
>
> !     An error occurred while installing ruby-2.3.8
>
> !
>
> !     This version of Ruby is not available on Heroku-18. The minimum
>   supported version
>
> !     of Ruby on the Heroku-18 stack can found at:
>
> !
>
> !
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
>
> !
>
> !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
>
> !     Push failed

As you can see I'm using 2.3.8 ruby version, the one supported by Heroku, and I still can't push my app to it. what's the problem?

Comment: You can downgrade heroku stack to solve this issue. Solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354444/how-can-i-solve-this-trouble-to-deploy-a-rails-app-to-heroku?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the link provided as part of the output you will see it has the following:

> 2.3.8 : patchlevel 459, Rubygems : 2.5.2.3 (2.3 is not available on Heroku-18)
>
> Version 2.3.8 is not supported on Heroku-18

Try upgrading your app to 2.4.5 or above.

Answer (score 0):

Check the latest version of ruby in this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes

then run the latest one `rvm install ruby-2.4.6`

type `ruby -v` in the terminal, you should see ruby 2.4.6.

If it still shows you ruby 2.0., run `rvm use ruby-2.4.6 --default`.

This solve mine

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already outdated but if anyone still having problem with this kind of ruby version issue. please try to update your `bin/rails` file using the command.
`bundle binstubs bundler --force`

https://bundler.io/man/bundle-binstubs.1.html