# trouble pushing app to heroku, ruby version error - RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, heroku, rvm

remote:  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-2.3.1
this version of ruby is not available on heroku-18

so, when I run Ruby -v, I get: 
ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-linux]

and my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "2.6.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'bootstrap', '>=4.0'
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'

end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Everything is running locally, what am I doing wrong? to note, i am using RVM - Is there anything special that i need to do to use RVM with heroku ?

Comment: Modify ruby "~> 2.6.0", to ruby "2.6.0" and then bundle and try pushing again to heroku

Comment: I am getting the same exact error, "An error occurred while installing ruby-2.3.1"

Comment: Check Gemfile.lock if it has been bundled with the correct ruby version as heroku detects from this file only. If not then delete this file and bundle again

Comment: i deleted gemfile.lock, then ran bundle install - same error - sorry - I really appreciate your help....also in gemfile.lock I confirmed that there Ruby Version is 2.6.0, same as gemfile

Comment: You can downgrade heroku stack to solve this issue. Solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354444/how-can-i-solve-this-trouble-to-deploy-a-rails-app-to-heroku?answertab=active#tab-top