# Hit a snag on step 4.7

Tags: ruby, heroku

I have started learning to code through The Odin Project and has tried to get past Step 4.7 of Your First Rails App. Have tried everything, even upgrading and has asked others about the issue and I keep getting this error each time I have tried to deploy to Heroku.

I have tried upgrading to the latest version of Ruby but I still haven't been able to progress. I have used tutorials and commands from other websites and from other developers as well.

```
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-2.3.7
remote:  !     
remote:  !     This version of Ruby is not available on Heroku-18. The minimum supported version
remote:  !     of Ruby on the Heroku-18 stack can found at:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

Once able to deploy to Heroku, a link to the app should appear afterwards you would have to migrate the data base to Heroku before your app becomes available to view on web.

Comment: You can downgrade heroku stack to solve this issue. Solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354444/how-can-i-solve-this-trouble-to-deploy-a-rails-app-to-heroku?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever check those log/messages?
As it stated, the error is because your requested ruby version's not supported by Heroku.
Check thie link [given](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes).

Change your Gemfile, to use ruby `2.4.5` , `2.5.3` or `2.6.0`.

Comment: After playing with it for 3 days, I was able to deploy my app after changing the Gemfile from 2.3.7 to 2.5.3 as well as Gemfile.lock and .ruby-version.